# Trying to create a String with different values with a loop

Tags: arrays, swift, loops

I have a String (url) which I want to add a value using string interpolation every time the loop runs. If there are 3 values in the coordinates array, the finishedUrl have to add + "|(coordinate)" 3 times.

The problem is every time the loop runs, the coordinate variable is replace by a new value.

```
var coordinates = [String]()  //[28,-10 , 30,-11 , 12,-10] 3 values
let url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?"
let finishedUrl = ""    

for coordinate in self.coordinates{
   finishedUrl = url + "|\(coordinate)"
}
```

How can I do to create a string that add the coordinate value every time the loop runs?

The result I'm looking for should be:

```
finishedUrl = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?|28,-10|30,-11|12,-10"
```

Thank You!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each iteration you are assigning url + (the next coordinate) to finishedUrl and overwriting it as you go.

Try:

```
for coordinate in self.coordinates{
   url += "|\(coordinate)"
}

finishedUrl = url;
```